# Arbitrage opportunities

Tags: options, arbitrage

I want to write a program that can find arbitrage in the curve of call prices for different strike K.
So if I have a time serie with the price of call prices for different strikes and same time to maturity I want to find if there's is an arbitrage opportunity. Is there a simple way of doing so?

I was thinking about listing all the type of known simple arbitrage that exists: butterfly arbitrage, curve should be strictly increasing in the strike price and basically just manually check for these two (are there other simple arbitrage that are easy to spot from the time serie that I am missing here?)

Otherwise are there more efficient way than just listing all arbitrage that exists and check for each of them one by one?

Comment: "if I have a times series with call prices" keep in mind that no-arbitrage relationships require simultaneous prices (in fact simulateous bid-asks), if you use 2 prices from different moments, even in the same day, results contrary to no-arbitrage can easily occur.